# CXF + SSL + WebLogic 9.10

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws, cxf, weblogic9.x

I im developing a web application, its a servlet which basically acts as a front end for a web service, im using CXF for the web service client, the application is running on a WebLogic 9.10 server,  every thing was working ok until the project owner decided to add ssl supprt, no big problem, since im using cxf whitout spring, i managed to configure the TLS parameters in the http conduit of the service client,also configured a keystore whit the server key, ca root certificate and a client certificate, tested under a development tomcat instance and worked fine.

Problems started when redeployed the app to the weblogic server again and started getting weird errors, first one was:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient
```

then i realized than weblogic was loading its own implementation of JAX-WS, ok no probelm, just added a weblogic.xml whit "prefer-web-inf-classes" set to true, redeployed and now i got this exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, com/adinfi/imgsvc/cm/service/CMBGenericWebServiceService, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/ws/Service, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
```

That one got me, i thought something was wrong whit the class path,so i started removing jars from the application  and still got some more linkage errors, last one i got is this:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler"
```

and this is how the "Web-Inf/lib/" directory of my application looks like now:

```
   classes12.jar

   classes12.zip

   common.jar

   common.resources.jar

   commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar

   commons-discovery.jar

   commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

   commons-logging-api.jar

   commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar

   cxf-2.2.5.jar

   log4j-1.2.8.jar

   ras.jar

   runtimefw.jar

   wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar

   wss4j-1.5.8.jar

   xalan-2.7.1.jar

   xml-resolver-1.2.jar

   XmlSchema-1.4.5.jar

   xmlsec-1.4.3.jar
```

Any idea what im doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rollback the `prefer-web-inf-classes` stuff and follow the WebLogic specific instructions from the [**Application Server Specific Configuration Guide**](http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html) of CXF's documentation. 
More precisely, provide a `weblogic-application.xml` as explained in the second option [Pack war in an ear, deploy the ear with weblogic-application.xml](http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-WebLogic) with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
    <application-param>
        <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </application-param>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

Follow the additional steps of [this post](http://www.nabble.com/RE:-Getting-error-while-deploying-on-weblogic-9.2-but-able-to-do-in-tomcat-p15981374.html) if required.

Comment: Wow somehow managed to miss that piece of documentation....right now im off to my work, will try immediately, thanks for reply =)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to remember how I solved it.
I think the issue disappeared after removing the import of **stax-api** in my pom.xml file.
More precisely, in my case I had to exclude it from poi-ooxml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```